# Right to left layout support

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin.forms, right-to-left

I'm trying to support Arabic language right to left layout support but turns out there is no way you can support right to left in Xamarin Forms.

I even tried dependency service and called right to left layout by myself. Here is the code:

```
public CultureInfo SetLocale(string locale)
    {
        var netLocale = locale.Replace("_", "-");
        var ci = new CultureInfo(netLocale);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr1)
        {
            // Change locale settings in the app.
            var dm = Forms.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
            var conf = Forms.Context.Resources.Configuration;
            conf.Locale = new Java.Util.Locale(locale);
            Forms.Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(conf, dm);

            if (locale == "en")
                (Forms.Context as MainActivity).Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = Android.Views.View.LayoutDirectionLtr;
            else
                (Forms.Context as MainActivity).Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = Android.Views.View.LayoutDirectionRtl;
        }

        return ci;
    }
```

Comment: Guess you need to align every element by it's own e.g. `<Entry HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />`

Comment: @Nitro.de is correct, you need to realign all of the localized elements. You can do this with a binding + valueconverter, or with a custom attached property, or with brute force coding.

Comment: I would try to implement it and will post back :)

Comment: @Nitro.de, It's not the solution when the app is multi-culture and user can change the lang of app (regardless the OS lang)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late, here are some links:

[there is layoutDirection](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Util.LayoutDirection.Rtl/) and [on this forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61652/rtl-layout) they have answered it:

> To detect when RTL is required, I use this bit of code (I found reflection was required, as the IsRightToLeft property was unexpectedly inaccessible):

```
bool rightToLeft = false;
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = thisCulture.TextInfo.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("IsRightToLeft");
object value = propertyInfo?.GetValue(thisCulture.TextInfo);
if (value is bool)
    rightToLeft = (bool) value;
```

> After that, it was mostly a case of switching a few properties:

```
 HorizontalOptions = rightToLeft ? LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand : LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
 HorizontalTextAlignment = rightToLeft ? TextAlignment.End : TextAlignment.Start;
```

more links
 [Adjust layout and fonts, and support RTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/adjust-layout-and-fonts--and-support-rtl)

Comment: Please add some content to the answer beyond the links that can easily go stale.

Comment: Very true, Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

You could set the dir property of html if language is arabic.

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Comment: That only applies to HTML, not native Xamarin.

Comment: bro its xamarin :/